# Robocopy: not deleting folders containing excluded files

Tags: robocopy

I want to mirror two folders, but to exclude certain file types (e.g. js files). I can do that with /XF option.

The problem I run into is that if there is a folder Foo with js file in Destination folder, but there is no Foo folder in Source folder - robocopy command bellow deletes the Foo folder on the destination side together with the js files in it.

Robocopy.exe d:\Source d:\Destination /E /PURGE /XF *.js /COPYALL /FFT

What I would like is to exclude from deliting folders that contain excluded files.

Comment: In my experience, Robocopy _doesn't_ delete excluded files. I'm actually here looking for how to make it do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you apply /PURGE it will delete, it will delete any file/folder that doesn't exist in your source folder.

If you need to maintain that folder, you need to create that folder in the source and remove the /PURGE switch.

```
Robocopy.exe d:\Source d:\Destination /E /XF *.js /COPYALL /FFT
```